# No Data from Service to Controller to Scope -> Result Undefined Angularjs Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

My problem is, that the controller just send an undefiend and not the data from http of service. I inspect it with chrome. I am new at ionic. By calling the AppSqliDBFactory.getMasterdataId() method, it shows an undefiend, also at the scope variable.

```
.controller('ReadMasterdataCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $ionicNavBarDelegate, MasterdataService, AppSqliDBFactory){

$scope.masterdataId;
$scope.masterdataData;

AppSqliDBFactory.getMasterdataId().then( function (masterdata){
    $scope.masterdataId = masterdata[0].masterdataId;       
}).catch(function (err){
    console.log(err);
});

        //here is the error -> no data at "$scope.masterdataData = masterdata;"
        MasterdataService.getMasterdataDB($scope.masterdataId)
                .then(function (masterdata) {
                    $scope.masterdataData = masterdata;
                    console.log("getMasterdataDB respont");
                    console.log($scope.masterdataData);
                }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

})

//Service
.factory('MasterdataService', function ($q, $http, SERVER_URL) {
//Create JSON Object
var srv = {};
//Array for JSON Objects
srv.masterdata = [];


srv.getMasterdataDB = function (masterdataId) {
    var deferred = $q.defer(); 

    var masterdata; 

    var masterdataId = masterdataId;

    var baseUrl = 'xxxx';



    $http.get(SERVER_URL + baseUrl + masterdataId).success(function (response){
        masterdata = response[0]; 
        console.log(masterdata);
        return deferred.resolve(masterdata);

    }).error(function (err){
        return deferred.reject(err);
    });        

    return deferred.promise;
    //return srv.getMasterdata();
};

 // Public API
return {
      getMasterdataDB: function ( masterdataId) {
        return $q.when(srv.getMasterdataDB( masterdataId));
    }
};
});
```

Comment: $scope.masterdataId = masterdata[0].masterdataId;  is working. I am getting an value. The problem is at MasterdataService.getMasterdataDB($scope.masterdataId)

Answer (score 1):

Simplified:

```js
AppSqliDBFactory.getMasterdataId().then(function (masterdata) {
  $scope.masterdataId = masterdata[0].masterdataId;       
});

MasterdataService.getMasterdataDB($scope.masterdataId).then(function (masterdata) {
  $scope.masterdataData = masterdata;
});
```

When `MasterdataService.getMasterdataDB()` is called, `AppSqliDBFactory.getMasterdataId()` may not have been resolved yet, so `$scope.masterdataId` can be undefined (which is probably what is happening in your case).

You have to call `AppSqliDBFactory.getMasterdataId()` after `AppSqliDBFactory.getMasterdataId()` has been resolved:

```js
AppSqliDBFactory.getMasterdataId().then(function (masterdata) {
  $scope.masterdataId = masterdata[0].masterdataId;    
  MasterdataService.getMasterdataDB($scope.masterdataId).then(function (masterdata) {
    $scope.masterdataData = masterdata;
  });
});
```

Or with [chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining):

```js
AppSqliDBFactory.getMasterdataId().then(function (masterdata) {
  $scope.masterdataId = masterdata[0].masterdataId;    
  return MasterdataService.getMasterdataDB($scope.masterdataId);
}).then(function (masterdata) {
  $scope.masterdataData = masterdata;
});
```

Comment: Thank You, I solved the problem same way. So I am really happy for your solution.

Comment: @Christoph Glad I could help, don't forget to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) then ;)